# Logback asyncAppender seems to be not thread safe

Tags: logging, logback, appender, rollingfileappender, log4j2

I have created an AsyncAppender by adding my own SUMMARY_APPENDER inside it.

ASYNC Appender is as below

```
 <appender name="ASYNC" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
 <discardingThreshold>2</discardingThreshold>
 <appender-ref ref="SUMMARY_APPENDER" />
 <!--   <appender-ref ref="PROCESSING" /> -->
 </appender>
```

I have created another SUMMARY_APPENDER

```
<appender name="SUMMARY_APPENDER"
    class="com.my.test.logger.async.MyRollingAppender">
    <file>./logs/summary.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="com.my.test.logger.async.MyTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- daily rollover -->
        <fileNamePattern>./logs/%d{yyyy-MM-dd,aux}/summary.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
        </fileNamePattern>
        <TimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
            class="com.my.test.logger.async.MySizeTimeBasedPolicy">
            <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
        </TimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        <!-- keep 30 days' worth of history -->
        <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>
            %d{ISO8601} [%t] %p %c %L - %m%n
        </pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

The RollingPolicy are properly extended by my Custom Appenders.

- I have exported this as a custom jar with logback.xml.
- I added it to classpath of new java project.
- Ran some concurrent program to log to ensure that all the threads are logging it simultaneously and correctly.

Program is as below, I created TestLogger1 ,2...5 and ran those.

```
 public class TestingLogger {
 private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestingLogger.class);
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    LoggerContext lc = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
    StatusPrinter.print(lc);
    for (int i = 1; i < 100000; i++) {
        log.debug(" Testing Logger " + i);
    }
  }
}
```

**Each of the Logger has .1 Million logs , so at the end I expect .5 Million**

Kindly help me to understand on how to synchronise the logging and also let me know If I am doing anything wrong.

Comment: I see only one `main(...)` method in your code, without threads. If you are trying to write to a common file from several JVM (ie several OS processes), you can't ensure proper synchronized writing.

Comment: @GuillaumeDarmont I executed on the same JVM with multiple Main method threads, I have just written here only one.

Answer (score 7):

From the manual:

discardingThreshold

By default, when the blocking queue has 20% capacity remaining, it will drop events of level TRACE, DEBUG and INFO, keeping only events of level WARN and ERROR. To keep all events, set discardingThreshold to 0.

So set this property to 0 from 2 in your configuration and you should see all messages arrive in the log file.